# How can I create guessing options as user types in input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I add guessed options for the input box as a user starts writing his word? For example, if the user wants to type 'London' when he writes lon or lo, guessed word should appear below the input box and user can select it. How can I do that with jQuery or JavaScript? Is there any library?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Paste your code please.

Comment: try with [datalist tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add jquery plugin in your web and use autocomplete.

note: you should have a big record to make your autocomplete perfect or have a big array list.. your code might look something like this

```
//HTML
<input type="text" id="autocomplete">
//JAVASCRIPT
var countryTags = [
      "america",
      "london",
      "philippines",
    ];
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
source:countryTags });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, jQuery has an autocomplete plugin which I think is what you are looking for. [Here is the plugin](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Comment: Question asking for libraries should not be a question on SO, so it don't make much sense to answer off topic questions

Answer (score 0):

1. make array of predefined words
2. make function that is called by onchange event
3. In that function:

```js
 function myFunction (text) {
    var anotherArray = [];
    for (i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i].substring(0,text.length) == text) {
            anotherArray.push(myArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

For better functioning I recommend comparing strings as lowercases, because "london" != "London".

And if you want to be able to search from the middle like: "don" to find "London" use str.indexOf and if it's > 1 then it's a match

Comment: I'll fix substring as I noticed I wrote it the wrong way